# why are brackets used in this assert_equal statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, variable-types

In the book Agile Web Development with Rails, they're teaching how to write test unit cases:

```
test "product price must be positive" do
  product = Product.new(title: "By Book Title",
                        description: "yyy",
                        image_url: "zzz.jpg")
  product.price = -1
  assert product.invalid?
  assert_equal ["must be greater than or equal to 0.01"], product.errors[:price]
end
```

Concerning the assert_equal statement, why are brackets needed around the "must be greater than..." string.  I'm assuming variable types are coming into play here, but need some clarification on why.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`model.errors[:field]`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#working_with_validation_errors-errors-2) always returns an array of strings, even if there's only a single error.

If the assert was done without the `[` `]` it would always be false because it would be comparing a string to an array.

```
assert_equal "must be greater than or equal to 0.01", ["must be greater than or equal to 0.01"]    
=> false

assert_equal ["must be greater than or equal to 0.01"], ["must be greater than or equal to 0.01"]   
=> true
```

Comment: Ah hah! So if there are multiple errors for that field, does assert_equal try to find a match with the other returned errors, or does it just try to match the first one?

Comment: If there are multiple errors for that field the assert will fail. All the content/elements of the arrays have to be identical.

Comment: So, it sounds like there's probably a better way to do this that I'll learn later on in the book.  Thanks for helping me understand the types issue!